# html and css menu issue (probably z-index issue)

Tags: html, css, z-index

I am working on [this site](http://runwayexpress.com.au) for a client of mine.

Issue is that the dropdown menu on the home page hides behind the embedded youtube player. It seems to be a simple css problem involving z-index but I have been unable to solve it. Maybe it has something to do with the youtube embed.

I have tried to set the z-index of the menu but it does not seem to be effective.

I almost forgot to tell you that the problem occurs on IE9 specifically.

Also, I'm not a css expert so please just point out what the issue is.

Comment: put a code to resolve your problem

Comment: Its simple css and html you can see from the browser console. Sorry but there is a whole lot of css involved. How much should i put there?

Comment: yeh a already seen it on your link, it's ok try with my code placed below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use below code for youtube iframe:

```
<iframe width="597" height="323" src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/Rahab_AMCkE?wmode=transparent" rel="0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

**Add `wmode=transparent"` just after the source(src) of video**

This is a Flash issue. When embedding Flash, the default is `wmode=window`, making the SWF overlay any HTML object on the page. To avoid that, use `wmode=opaque` or `wmode=transparent` which allow HTML elements to overlap SWF content. For more info and the difference between the two see Adobe's [help](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html#main_Browser_support_for_Window_Mode__wmode__values).

Comment: Thank mate ... that did it for me ... guess the allowfullscreen attribute was the issue here?

Comment: @hussain Welcome! wmode="transparent" what i added. I'll update this in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Define your css style like this.

```
.navigation ul ul{
z-index:3;
}
.lcd{
position:relative;
z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: :( It still does not make any difference. And i have already tried that.

Comment: but you have don't define .lcd position check to your css and now you just define z-index but z-index not work if you have no define any position

Answer (score 0):

use

```
_z-index:1000001;
```

do not remove

```
z-index: //whatever;
```

Comment: Where do i put this _z-index? I mean which class?

Comment: try with you css add new line .navigation ul li ul li {_z-index:1000001;  }